# wkhtml2pdf rendering size issue

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Taking care of removing any paddings or margins, I have created a basic html page containing a single table whose height is supposed to be 297mm (A4 paper height):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    body 
    {
      padding: 0; /* Padding for content */
      margin: 0 auto; /* Margin from container */  
    }     
    table
    {
      padding: 2.5mm 5mm; /* Padding for content */    
      margin:0; /* Margin from container */

      width:100%;
      border-spacing:0;
      background-color:yellow;
    
      height:297mm;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr style="height:3%"><td style="background-color:RGB(235, 105, 11)">1</td></tr>
      <tr style="height:30%"><td style="background-color:RGB(47,52,57)">2</td></tr>
      <tr style="height:17%"><td style="background-color:RGB(94,98,102)">3</td></tr>
      <tr style="height:auto"><td style="background-color:RGB(255,255,255)">4</td></tr>
      <tr style="height:13%"><td style="background-color:RGB(47,52,57)">5</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I'm trying to render this in A4 PDF format using [wkhtml2pdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) utility (again taking care of removing any margin and/or padding:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --page-size A4 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 -B 0 .\testsize.html testsize.pdf
```

Anyway rendered table height does not seem to be 297mm in PDF document. It appears to be smaller:

[image: Rendering]

It is only when modifying table height to `height: 371mm` that I can have it to fill full A4 paper height in the PDF document (NB: 371mm/291mm is almost a x1.25 ratio).

**Do you have any idea for where this ratio in rendering height comes from and how i may fix it ?**

- NB1: As far as I know wkhtml2pdf uses [webkit](https://webkit.org/) as rendering engine
- NB2: When displaying html code in chrome with zoom=x1, displayed height already doesn't match with A4 PDF document placed side-by-side and zoom also set to x1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure `wkhtmltopdf` respects the `mm` CSS unit. That said, you could try to adjust some command line options that modify the ratio between the HTML document sizes and the rendered PDF:

- `--zoom <float>`: I think this one is the most important in your case. Try to set to `--zoom 1.25`, the ratio you estimated.
- `--disable-smart-shrinking`: In my experience, this command often prevents element sizes to have unexpected values.
- `--dpi <number>`: I'm not sure if this will change something, but try `300` or `600`.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs. `--zoom` seems to do the trick albeit I need to better check how this will affect image/font size in more complex document (I want to use html+css to create automatic reports and stop using Latex for that). Further readings now quite let me better understand why working with absolute units in html+css can be a nightmare on multiple desktop/tablet/phone/printer rendering devices (http://robert.ocallahan.org/2010/01/css-absolute-length-units_12.html)

Comment: --disable-smart-shriking worked for me. but the pdf is still has incorrect font.

Comment: @Ben you most likely need to install Windows fonts, since Linux doesn't come with most of the main ones. https://askubuntu.com/questions/55643/install-ms-truetype-fonts-system-wide-for-all-users

Comment: @BrianLeishman I was trying windows binary on a Win7 workstation. Not sure why, but maybe it has something to do with font substitution. I was trying to print a label via pdf, b/c none of the authoring tools at hand seems smart enough to achieve a good universal template for all the product using the same label paper. CSS worked well for the dynamic layout, Most likely the issue was about characerts e.g. (TM) (R) (phi) etc.